# Error while Django Database Backup - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extension'

Tags: python, django, database-backups

I am trying to use [django-dbbackup v2.3.3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-dbbackup/2.3.3) to backup the database of django project (`django-1.8.4`, `python - 3.4.3`)

I am following this [django-dbbackup](http://django-dbbackup.readthedocs.org/en/latest/storage.html#local-disk) documentation.

Below is my project settings for **DATABASES** and **DATABASE_BACKUP**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django_admin_bootstrapped',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.gis',

    'authtools',
    'crispy_forms',
    'easy_thumbnails',
    'rest_framework',
    'dbbackup',

    'profiles',
    'location',
    'maps'

)

DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.spatialite'

# DATABASE BACKUP SETTINGS
DBBACKUP_STORAGE = 'dbbackup.storage.filesystem_storage'
DBBACKUP_STORAGE_OPTIONS ={'location':'/home/altius/locateme/src/backup/'}
```

And I am getting the following error -

```
Backing Up Database: db.sqlite3
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "manage.py", line 13, in <module>
     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
   File"/usr/local/lib/python3.4/distpackages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
     utility.execute()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 444, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/dbbackup/utils.py", line 100, in wrapper
func(*args, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/dbbackup/management/commands/dbbackup.py", line 54, in handle
self.save_new_backup(database)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/dbbackup/management/commands/dbbackup.py", line 66, in save_new_backup
filename = self.dbcommands.filename(self.servername)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/dbbackup/dbcommands.py", line 278, in filename
extension = self.settings.extension
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extension'
```

I tried to look into other errors but in vain to find out the solution for 
 **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extension'**

There are several **AttributeError** like `append`, `strip`, `format` etc. but not able to find **extension** error.

Am I missing some more settings ? What else  need to do to get rid of this error to backup the database locally for django-project ?

Answer (score 0):

From its source code, I think `django-dbbackup` doesn't have support for SpatiaLite.

Check the source of method [`_get_settings()`](https://github.com/django-dbbackup/django-dbbackup/blob/master/dbbackup/dbcommands.py#L241) (which sets the value of `self.settings`) it shows that the code is fetching database settings for only MySQL, PostGIS, PostGreSQL and SQLite.

Since, it matches none of the listed databases, `self.settings` gets set to `None` and hence when you get the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extension'` when it tries to fetch `self.settings.extension`. You can give it a try in Python shell.

```
>>> settings = None
>>> settings.extension

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#34>", line 1, in <module>
    settings.extension
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extension'
```

Although, there is no specific mention of the list of databases `django-dbbackup` supports in the docs. It would be better if you could confirm this once with the authors.

**EDIT:** OP has created an [issue](https://github.com/django-dbbackup/django-dbbackup/issues/148) on the GitHub repo of django-backup. Do check the link to check for updates regarding support for SpatiaLite.

Comment: Estiberio - There is mentioned about 3 databases including Mysql, Postgre and Sqlite  in the documentation (http://django-dbbackup.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html), but nothing mention about Spatialite issues. I created one issue.Let see what is the outcome.

Thanks